# OpenLayer/OpenStreetMap Hike&Bike Map

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openstreetmap

In my SPA i want to inlcude openstreetmap via OpenLayer per JavaScript. This works fine. But how can i change the map type to the Hike&Bike Map like here: http://hikebikemap.de/ ?

currently i am using the following code:

```
var zoom            = 11;
var fromProjection  = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
var toProjection    = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
var markers         = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( 'Markers' );
var map             = new OpenLayers.Map();
var mapnik          = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.addLayer(markers);

var position  = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lng, lat).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));
map.setCenter(position, zoom);
map.render(element);
```

and got this:
[image]

but i want this kind of map:

[image]

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the linked page's source you'll see that they're adding several WMS layers apart from OSM:

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
var cycle = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap("Cycle Map");
var osma = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Osmarender("Osmarender");

map.addLayers([ osm, cycle, osma ]);
```

If you want more than one layer to be available to the user you'll need a `OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher`.

Note that the sub-types (`OSM.Mapnik`, `OSM.CycleMap`, `OSM.Osmarender`) are not part of standard OpenLayers distribution, looking at [one of the source files](https://toolserver.org/~osm/libs/openstreetmap/latest/OpenStreetMap.js) seems like they're simply convenience classes that define different tile data source, they don't provide any special functionality per se, for example:

```
OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, {
    initialize: function(name, options) {
        var url = [
            "http://a.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
            "http://b.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
            "http://c.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"
        ];
        options = OpenLayers.Util.extend({
            numZoomLevels: 19,
            buffer: 0
        }, options);
        var newArguments = [name, url, options];
        OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.prototype.initialize.apply(this, newArguments);
    },
    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap"
});
```

Comment: Just a little correction: these are TMS layers, not WMS layers.

Comment: And also please respect the Tile Usage Policies of the single servers that might restrict you from using the tiles in your service: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS