# javascript/jQuery getJSON very slow with a inner loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to render DOM for layerswitcher, with about 1200 divs. The problem can be simplified as follows.

This is very fast (3 seconds or so):

```
var allLayers = [layerMapnik, layerCycleMap];

for(var ii = 0; ii < 1200; ++ii) {
    console.log("ii = " + ii.toString());
    var groupName = "wms/Transit/railroad/image/" + ii;
    var layName = "CycleMap" + ii.toString();
    var oneLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(layName, "http://whatever/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}", {visibility: false, group:groupName});
    allLayers.push(oneLayer);
}

console.log("adding layers");

map.addLayers(allLayers);

$.getJSON("sampleArray.json", {}, function( doc ) {
    console.log(doc.length);
 });
```

But once the for-loop is put inside the getJson callback, it's painfully slow and freezes the browser, even when the for-loop is not reading the 'doc' at all!

```
var allLayers = [layerMapnik, layerCycleMap];

$.getJSON("sampleArray.json", {}, function( doc ) {
    console.log(doc.length);
    for(var ii = 0; ii < 1200; ++ii) {
        console.log("ii = " + ii.toString());
        var groupName = "wms/Transit/railroad/image/" + ii;
        var layName = "CycleMap" + ii.toString();
        var oneLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(layName, "http://whatever/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}", {visibility: false, group:groupName});
        allLayers.push(oneLayer);
    }
    console.log("adding layers");

    map.addLayers(allLayers);
 });
```

No matter how simple the json file is sampleArray.json:

```
[
  {
    "a": 123,
    "b": 456
  },
  {
    "c": "ccc",
    "d": "ddd"
  } 
]
```

Did I use the getJSON or callback wrong? Or it is an OpenLayer thing?

I also tried $.each instead of for-loop, no help.

Comment: 1200 iterations with a nested for-loop? That will definitely compound the lag. 1200 divs on a page probably won't run well either way. I'd seek a solution involving pagination.

Comment: My impression is adding 1200 divs to DOM is not that bad, as the 'fast example' shows http://blog.korynunn.com/javascript/the-dom-isnt-slow-you-are/  . I'm confused on why it's getting super slow in a callback.

Comment: Is the problem that the loop is slow, or that it takes a while for getJSON to finish before the callback is actually called?  You can try add some console log messages to check how long the getJSON takes to pull in your JSON file.

Comment: The loop is fast on its own ( < 3 seconds for 1200-loop). And the getJSON is fast too ( < 2 second for the small file attached). It's the combination of the two is slow ( > 30 seconds and freezes browser).

Comment: The OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap is a TMS (slippy map tile layer), see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005356/openlayer-openstreetmap-hikebike-map and should not be added 1000 times like this in a loop. I have no idea why there is such a performance issue between the doing it in a loop and doing it in a loop in a callback, but adding the same map tiles 1000 times is definitely a no no, as well as being pretty much against OSM use policies. Nice link about the DOM above, btw.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion and thanks for reminding the OSM use policy. I actually have my own tile server, serving more than 1000 layers (5 layers each for > 200 countries), and the OSM above is just for demo purposes.

Comment: if you want to know bottle necks in javascript you run through the profiler and even put breakpoints if need be, but as far as I know, OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ  takes in a json object / collection anyway, just return back the correct format and insert once as a collection

Comment: Ok. I still don't understand what you are trying to do though. OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ will call tiles from a server based on your view extents. You add one XYZ layer for each type, OSM cyclemap, Google street, whatever, there is no need to add inside a loop like this. This way you would end up 1200 layers in your layer switcher. As davethecoder says, you initialize once with a JSON object as options, and add the layer once to the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions, for future reference.

The adding LayerSwitcher should be inside the callback function too. Because the whole LayerSwitcher div should be generated BEFORE adding it to the main html, otherwise the redraw for every added layer in the switcher slows things down and freezes the browser.

Also, it is helpful to have the $.ajax call outside the $(document).ready(), to speed things up, since the data fetching does not need to wait for the $(document)